# How to find a string that follows after the first "of" of a range

Tags: regex

I have the following string

```
... of 7th July 2019 , signed by the District Director of the National Service of ENCAC.
```

I wish to find

```
the National Service of ENCAC
```

I have this regular expression to search from "signed by" , but I would like it to search from the first "of" that follows "signed by"

```
(?<=signed by)(.*)(?=\.)
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: You might use `\bsigned\s+by\b.*?\bof\s([^.]+)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mssvGo/1)). Or, `\bsigned\s+by\b.*?\bof\s\K[^.]+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/mssvGo/2))

Comment: Now this is your third regex question already. Please always mention what tool/lang you're using. Availalble regex features differ among the implementations. Also it makes sense to describe the goal and/or include some code. "I wish to find" can mean: "I wish to extract" but also "I wish to replace"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match until the first occurrence of `of` after *signed by* instead of looking back with a lookbehind, then use a capture group and match the trailing dot.

```
\bsigned by\b.*?\bof\b\s([^.]*)\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lXH77Y/1)

If there can also not be a dot in between:

```
\bsigned by\b[^.]*?\bof\b\s([^.]*)\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sP8tRD/1)